# Openlayer map disappears after returning a PHP request through events

Tags: openlayers, php, qgis-openlayers-plugin, nosql

I generated an OpenLayers map using the 'QGIS2WEB' plugin in QGIS.

I am working on a program that, depending on the coordinates where the user clicks, will send them to a PHP controller. The controller will then query a Postgre SQL database and return the result through an event:

qgis2web.js:

```
...
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    window.livewire.emit('get_map_location_data', evt.coordinate);
});
...
```

Controller.php:

```
protected $listeners = ['get_map_location_data' => 'getMapLocationData'];

public function getMapLocationData($coord) {
        $someData = MyNoSQLQuery->first();
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('retrievedata', ['res_data' => $someData]);
    }
```

myView.php:

```
<div x-data="data()" ... @retrievedata.window="processData($event.detail.res_data)">
...
</div>
```

myScript.js:

```
function data() {
    return {
        ...
        processDataMarker: function (res) {
            // this.resize_map();
        },
        resize_map: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    map.updateSize()
                }, 300)
            }
            ...
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the map disappears after obtaining the result of the query to the controller, that is, after clicking on it. I tried, as shown in the code of "myScript.js," to apply the function "this.resize_map();" which updates the map's size after 300 milliseconds, but the map still doesn't get drawn.

Before Click:
[image: BEFORE CLICK]

After Click:
[image: AFTER CLICK]

No error or warning message is displayed; the map simply disappears.

Comment: Try the generic listeners https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253062/276

Comment: How could that solve the problem? Basically, everything works relatively well, except that the map stops displaying after receiving the response from the controller.